# FloatField in Django is not storing decimal places of a number

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

In the 'List' class of models.py 'cred' was previously IntegerField which I later updated to FloatField. While getting a number input from user, the integer ones are successfully being saved but lets say user selects 4.5; in such case only 4 is being saved.

```
class List(models.Model):
    item=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc=models.TextField(default='description!')
    cred=models.FloatField(default=0)
```

```
<form action="{% url 'updatecred' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="number" min="1" max="25" step=".5" name="Credits" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Credits">
</form>
```

Here,curr is a global variable which is an object of the 'List' class obtained in another function in views.py :

```
def updatecred(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        newcred=request.POST['Credits']
        global curr
        cr=float(newcred)
        curr.cred=cr
        curr.save()
        return redirect('Info')
```

When I try to access curr.cred somewhere else, it doesnt show any decimal point.

I even tried using DecimalField but even that doesnt work

Comment: Although not solving the problem: please *never* use a global variable. A web server is supposed to be stateless. By introducing a global variable, the "context" will "leak" over all requests.

Comment: Print/log the value you are receving to see where the decimal places go missing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `global curr`. Create new object using `curr = List()` or get existing from database if want to change in existing row.

**Sample Code:**

```
def updatecred(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        newcred=request.POST['Credits']
        curr = List()
        cr=float(newcred)
        curr.cred=cr
        curr.save()
        return redirect('Info')
```

Comment: Noted! Any input on how to solve the above stated problem?

Comment: You can use Django sessions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) if you want to share some data b/w multiple views. However, sessions would not help you to share model's object. can you specify the exact use case which you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) with `decimal_places`parameter.

Example:

```
from decimal import Decimal

class List(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField(default='description!')
    cred = models.DecimalField(default = Decimal('0.0'), decimal_places = 1, max_digits = 15)
```

Comment: try `print(cr)` befor and after this line `cr=float(newcred)` if user input 4.5. What is there in prints?

Comment: Its 4.5. Nothings wrong with the user input. But while storing 4.5 it beomes 4

Comment: and if you change `cr=float(newcred)` on `cr=Decimal(newcred)`?